# LINQ Count and Max together

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-core

Following SQL Server query returns total numbers of successful logins and the last login (a date type) by a user. What is the LINQ equivalent of this query?

```
SELECT username, COUNT(LoginDate) AS total,
MAX(LoginDate) AS last_login
FROM login_history
GROUP BY username
```

Can't figure out the last_login value in the following:

```
var query = _context.login_history.GroupBy(u => u.userName, (key, values) => new { user_name = key, count = values.Count(), last_login = ???? });
```

**UPDATE**:

For example, Every time user logs in his/her record is added as follows. Note that the hit column is just a counter adding 1 to each login record. In the example below `jsmith` has logged in total 5 times so far and his last login was at `7/24/2016 9:16`. T-Sql query result shown in second table below reflects jsmith's total logins and last login date:

```
UserName Login_hit  LoginDate
jsmith  1   7/20/2016 13:37
jsmith  1   7/19/2016 10:40
jsmith  1   7/24/2016 9:16
jsmith  1   7/19/2016 9:16
jsmith  1   7/15/2016 14:55
bdoe    1   7/15/2016 14:55
....
```

**Result of SQL query in SQL Server:**

```
UserName |Total Logins | LasLoginDate
jsmith   |  5          |  7/24/2016 9:16
bdoe     |  79         |  7/12/2016 14:41
talbert  |  23         |  7/8/2016 22:51
bdole    |  87         |  7/21/2016 17:56
mdukakus |  31         |  7/22/2016 9:01
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549271(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var query = _context.login_history
                    .GroupBy(u => u.userName, 
                            (key, values) => new { user_name = key,
                                                   count = values.Count(),
                                                   last_login = values.Max(e=>e.LoginDate)
                                                 });
```

Comment: Your suggested solution is showing total logins per date. I've added an UPDATE section to my original post with an example that shows we need total number of **all** logins by a user and when was the last time the user was logged in. T-sql query correctly displays this summary but LINQ does not. Maybe, my original post w/o an example was not clear.

Comment: per date? I'm not grouping per date, `values` are the login_story entities grouped by username, in other words, it is a collection of all the login stories per username, `Max` method return a value, i don't see how that is happening

Comment: Then I may be displaying it wrong. I'm returning `List<LHCountsViewModel> lstLH = _context.login_history.OrderBy(u => u.UserName).GroupBy(u => u.UserName, (key, values) => new LHCountsViewModel { user_name = key, count = values.Count(), last_login = values.Max(e => e.LoginDate) }).ToList();`  to the view that has `@model List<MyProj.Models.LHCountsViewModel>` and `@foreach (var item in Model)
            {....}` loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = from lh in login_history
            group lh by new
                  {
                    user_name = lh.user_name
                  } into g
                  select new {
                    user_name = g.Key.user_name,
                    count = g.Count(),
                    last_login = g.Max(l => l.LoginDate)
                  };
```

Comment: Your suggested solution is showing total logins per date. Please see my comment to `@octavioccl` below.